# How to make the movement in this graphics.py code more fluent?

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

I just started using graphics.py and am attempting to make some moving rain.

```
from graphics import *
import random as r

rects = []
colorList = [color_rgb(255, 170, 204), color_rgb(255, 187, 204), color_rgb(255, 204, 204), 
             color_rgb(255, 221, 204), color_rgb(255, 238, 204)]
def main():
    r.seed()
    win = GraphWin("Random Squares", 800, 800)
    win.setBackground("black")
    for i in range(3000):
        x1 = r.randint(0,800)
        x2 = r.randint(0,10)
        y1 = x1+5
        y2 = x2+20
        var = Rectangle(Point(x1,x2), Point(y1,y2))
        rects.append(var)
        rects[i].setFill(r.choice(colorList))
        rects[i].draw(win)
        for i in range(len(rects)):
            rects[i].move(0,r.randint(10,100))
            update(10000)
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The issue I think I'm having is that the movement update is occurring as each new rectangle is added.
Can anyone help me come up with a better way to do this?

Comment: The `GraphWin` class has a keyword argument named `autoflush` whose default value is `True`, try supplying `autoflush=False` and see if that helps.

Comment: @martineau Wow that helped significantly! What exactly is autoflush doing in graphWin? Thanks!

Comment: Frank: Am not 100% sure. There's a comments about it in the `graphics.py` module that mentions it being undocumented and having something to do with compatibility with IDLE (the IDE included with Python which, like `graphics`, is based on `tkinter`)

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the input!

Comment: Being able to read the source code of the modules you're using is often a good way to answer questions you have about how it works (assuming the code in them isn't too advanced or has useful comments in it, of course).

Comment: I see, I figured the documentation would supply enough information to do this small project but it clearly didn't hold all the necessary information. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is forget about `autoflush` and `update()` until you've got your algorithm running at its fastest.  Specifically, you eventually end up with 3000 rectangles that you're updating even though there are never more than ~ 15 on the screen at a time.  You might be better off getting rid of rectangles that have fallen off the bottom:

```
from random import seed, randint, choice
from graphics import *

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 800

colorList = [
    color_rgb(255, 170, 204),
    color_rgb(255, 187, 204),
    color_rgb(255, 204, 204),
    color_rgb(255, 221, 204),
    color_rgb(255, 238, 204)
    ]

def main():
    seed()

    win = GraphWin("Random Squares", WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    win.setBackground("black")

    rects = []

    for _ in range(3000):
        for rect in list(rects):  # iterate over a shallow copy
            rect.move(0, randint(10, 100))

            if rect.getP1().getY() > HEIGHT:
                rect.undraw()
                rects.remove(rect)

        x1 = randint(0, WIDTH - 5)
        y1 = randint(0, 10)

        rect = Rectangle(Point(x1, y1), Point(x1 + 5, y1 + 20))
        rect.setFill(choice(colorList))
        rect.draw(win)

        rects.append(rect)

    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now we're only tracking ~15 rectangles instead of hundreds or thousands.  Only after you get your algorithm optimized, consider `autoflush` and `update()` if the performance is not to your liking:

```
def main():
    seed()

    win = GraphWin("Random Squares", WIDTH, HEIGHT, autoflush=False)
    win.setBackground("black")

    rects = []

    for _ in range(3000):
        for rect in list(rects):  # iterate over a shallow copy
            rect.move(0, randint(10, 100))

            if rect.getP1().getY() > HEIGHT:
                rect.undraw()
                rects.remove(rect)

        x1 = randint(0, WIDTH - 5)
        y1 = randint(0, 10)

        rect = Rectangle(Point(x1, y1), Point(x1 + 5, y1 + 20))
        rect.setFill(choice(colorList))
        rect.draw(win)

        update()

        rects.append(rect)

    win.getMouse()
    win.close()
```